# Removing lines between a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, plot, lm

The data in question are a Time Series data. I am trying to make a plot of Residual values Vs Fitted values but the scatter plot connects the points together. Is there anyways I can get rid of the connecting lines?
This is the code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(fpp2)
#head(fancy)

plot(fancy)
hist(fancy)
f_log = log(fancy)
hist(f_log)

lmod <- tslm(f_log ~ trend + season)
summary(lmod)
#residuals
res <- residuals(lmod)
plot(res, ylab="Residuals",xlab="Year")
plot(res,type = "p", ylab="Residuals",xlab="Year")
plot(lmod$fitted.values,res , xlab = "fitted values")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your residuals and values are of the ts:

```
> class(lmod$fitted.values)
[1] "ts"
> class(res)
[1] "ts"
```

So when you type plot(...), it calls [plot.ts](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot.ts):

```
plot.ts(lmod$fitted.values,res , xlab = "fitted values")
```

[image]

Which is what you see. So if you want to use the default plot function, you can do:

```
plot.default(lmod$fitted.values,res , xlab = "fitted values")
```

or using plot.ts:

```
plot(lmod$fitted.values,res , xlab = "fitted values",plot.type="single",xy.labels=FALSE)
```

[image]

or if you wanna see the labels:

```
plot(lmod$fitted.values,res , xlab = "fitted values",plot.type="single",xy.lines=FALSE,cex=0.5)
```

[image]